# Replace specific data in a csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to replace a specific data field in my csv file but am having issues.

My csv file is structured like:

```
user, password, role, id,
1, abc, 2, 3
2, def, 2, 4
3, ghi, 5, 5
```

I can read the file fine but when I want to replace a password using a textbox and button in a windows form I am having issues.

```
private void resetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\hughesa3\\Desktop\\test environment\\users.csv", encoding);

        foreach (var line in csvLines)
        {
            var values = line.Split(',');
            if (values[0].Contains(form2value))
            {
                values[1] = confirmPass.Text;
            }
    }
}
```

Form2value is their username, So what im trying do is: If the first column contains what was entered in form2value it will go to the 2nd column of that row.

I have tried this

```
 var values = line.Split(',');
            if (values[0].Contains(form2value))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(values[1]);
                values[1] = confirmPass.Text;
                MessageBox.Show(values[1]);
            }
    }
```

Just to see if the value is changing and it is but it is also displaying every value[1] when i only want it to if form2value was found.

I tried to explain this as best as I could but if anyone needs more info please let me know.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried adding MessageBox.Show(form2value) at the start to see what is in that variable? If it is empty or contains a space you will see all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Life would be easier for you if you used a data table..........

Here is an excerp...
DT is a DataTable.
Split the first line of your file and us dt.Columns.Add to add the column headings....

```
private void AddDataToDataTable()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(this.FileContents)))
    {
        //Igone headings & blank Lines
        string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //If blank line then skip line
            if (line == string.Empty) 
            {
                continue;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(this.Delimeter));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the `values` internal array you use in your code, not the file itself. In fact you're not writing the file anywhere, just reading it.

You'll need to: Read the file, get the line where the username is (if it exists), then write that specific line with the password.

Here's how you can do it:

```
private void resetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\hughesa3\\Desktop\\test environment\\users.csv", encoding);

    for (int i = 0; i < csvLines.Length; i++)
    {
        var values = csvLines[i].Split(',');
        if (values[0].Contains(form2value))
        {
            values[1] = confirmPass.Text;

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\hughesa3\\Desktop\\test environment\\users.csv", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding))
                {
                    for (int currentLine = 0; currentLine < csvLines.Length; ++currentLine)
                    {
                        if (currentLine == i)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", values));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(csvLines[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    writer.Close();
                }

                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a mistake in the previous piece of code. This: else { writer.WriteLine(csvLines[i]); }
to this: else { writer.WriteLine(csvLines[currentLine]); }